# 302 or 301 Redirect for This Scenario?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, 302-redirect, technical-seo

I have a client who had an existing page on their site - `example.com/page1`. They have had me create another page that covers similar material, but matches some other branding and messaging that they wanted. This is `example.com/page2`. There are two separate URLs here.

I am trying to figure out what I should do as far as redirects for the `page1` URL. They don't want people seeing `page1` right now, but they may want to use it again later. Is this best done as a 302? It wasn't clear to me for this particular scenario when I was doing my own research. I know it's not a 301 since this URL may come back separately. I also don't think deindexing it on Google would be a good idea either - I'm planning on leaving the URL in my sitemap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct: this is a job for the 302 (temporary) redirect, since you're planning to bring back this URL.

Of note, if you leave this redirect up for too long, search engines may start treating it as a 301. Ahrefs [describes this in more detail](https://ahrefs.com/blog/301-vs-302-redirects/), and while there is no set amount of time, this should be taken into consideration.

Also, if your redirected page can be found in your site nav, you may want to temporarily swap it out, to avoid any confusion on the part of the user. And when you bring it back, don't forget to 301 or 302 (whatever's appropriate) the second page.